# How to send a password in a GET request to access a REST resource

Tags: rest, http, jax-rs

I have a REST service that is **already secured with basic authentication** using the Authorization header.  This is used to access the service in general and is required for any request. i.e. "User1", "password1".

I have a "file" resource which can have an additional password associated with it (i.e a password protected Word document, PDF, etc), "docpassword".  What is the best way to send sensitive information like this?  I'm especially interested in how to send the password for a GET request, but I'd like to have a universal solution that will also work for POST requests.

Maybe a custom header?

Comment: I've decided to go with the custom header.  Since GET makes the most sense for retrieving a document resource I don't want to switch to a POST.  Putting the info in the body doesn't make sense for a GET request and in the URL it's not secure, so that really only leaves the  custom header option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTP protocol defines the standard [`Authorization`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.2) header for sending authentication data (credentials) to the server. This header is defined in the [RFC 7235](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235) (which makes the old [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) obsolete and updates the [RFC 2617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617)):

> [**4.2.  Authorization**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.2)
>
> The `Authorization` header field allows a user agent to authenticate
> itself with an origin server -- usually, but not necessarily, after
> receiving a `401` (Unauthorized) response. Its value consists of
> credentials containing the authentication information of the user
> agent for the realm of the resource being requested.
>
> ```
> Authorization = credentials
> ```
>
> [...]

Please note that the name of this HTTP header is unfortunate because it carries *authentication* data instead of *authorization*. Anyways, this is the standard headers for sending credentials in the HTTP protocol.

Once you are already using the [HTTP Basic Authentication Scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617#section-2) to authenticate the users in your application, I believe you are already using the standard [`Authorization`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.2) header.

---

I usually do not recommend custom headers, especially when the standard headers can be used instead, but your scenario seems not so common: You need to perform two authentications on the same request.

So, maybe a custom header such as `X-Auth-Document` or `Document-Authentication` with the document's password will be fine for `GET` requests. If you decide not using `GET` and decide using `POST` to access this resource, you can consider sending the document's password in the request paylod.

Anyways, don't forget using [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS): is highly advisable once you are sending sensitive data, such as credentials, over the wire. And HTTPS will protect you against the [man-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

Comment: I made a small edit to clarify my use case.  I am already using basic authentication to grant access to the service in general - i.e. the user must authenticate with user1:password1.  If they wanted to access a file resource that has an additional password, "docpassword", they would need to send this information as well.  "docpassword" is what I'm interested in sending securely, I'm sure that the Authorization header is the correct place for this.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP already has an authentication method, see for example this RFC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617

**Edit after clarification of question**: There is nothing preventing the server to make additional challenges, even based on single resource basis. I must admit I did not implement such a thing yet, but each authorization can have its own *realm*. You could specify different realms, even down to document level if you really want to. The server then can potentially make multiple challenges in each realm (first login, then document). Remember, you can cache successful authentications, either on the client (for a realm, like a browser does), or giving out cookies with a cached token.

This would have the advantage of avoiding a custom header, and be completely HTTP/REST conform. There may be some performance disadvantage, but it could be mitigated with some targeted caching.

Of course you can go with custom header if you want to, but normally REST would imply that the client goes in with no prior knowledge other than `mime-types` and the `HTTP` protocol. A custom header implies out-of-band prior knowledge.

Comment: I made a small edit to clarify my use case.  I am already using basic authentication to grant access to the service in general - i.e. the user must authenticate with user1:password1.  If they wanted to access a file resource that has an additional password, "docpassword", they would need to send this information as well. "docpassword" is what I'm interested in sending securely, I'm sure that the Authorization header is the correct place for this.

Comment: This sounds like an interesting solution, but for simplicity sake I've decided to go with the custom header.